# Unit Testing Synchronous Method With Code Calling Task

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, unit-testing

Given the following class:

```
public class TestAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public bool SomeExampleBool = false;

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { SomeExampleBool = true; });
    }
}
```

How would you write a valid unit test for `OnActionExecuting` that Asserts that `SomeExampleBool` is equal to `true`?

When writing a unit test and calling `OnActionExecuting`, then calling the Assert, the logic executes on a thread that will not have executed yet.  So the Assert fails.  Would you try something like `Thread.Sleep` for a couple of seconds?  Seems like a hack.  I'm sure there is a better way that I'm not thinking of but I'm reaching out to the community for some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to expose the `Task` returned by `StartNew` to anyone that you want to be able to:

1. Know when the operation finishes (by adding a continuation to it)
2. Know what the result is, if applicable
3. Know what any exceptions were, if applicable
4. Know if it was cancelled
5. Wait until it has finished

Since you're not exposing the return `Task` to anyone, you're just dropping it on the floor, there's no way for anyone else to wait on it, or run a continuation when it's done.  Typically you'd return the `Task` from that method.  If you can't, because it's an event handler, then you could potentially store the `Task` in a field or some other form of state that the caller would be able to access.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think about this before.  These aren't foreign concepts to me but when I tried thinking about unit testing I never considered returning the `Task` to a property or something similar.  Only thing kind of disgusting about the whole thing is making a public property for the task.

Answer (score 1):

`Task.Factory.StartNew` will return an instance of a `Task`.  If you call `task.Wait()`, you'll be guaranteed that the task will complete before executing the next line.  You should be able to just `Wait` for the task to complete, and then run your assertions after that.

Comment: This is in a MVC/WebAPI `ActionFilter`, so I don't want to `Wait` (would be blocking code).